# como pegar um objeto de uma array atraves id com angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Eu passo o id do objeto que vem de um ng-repeat através do $stateParams mais depois eu precisaria pegar o objeto do array referente ao id que vem da URL para exibir as informações. Minha duvida é se tenho que pegar esse objeto do JSON como faço ? 
E se tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso como por exemplo já mandar o objeto específico ao invés de somente a id ?

**controller :**

```
.controller('SingleController', function($scope,$http,$stateParams) {

 $stateParams.id;
    console.log($stateParams.id);

$scope.dados = Array();

    $http.get("js/dados.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.dados = data.dados;
        console.log($scope.dados);



    }).error(function(data){
        alert("Error...");
        console.log(data);
    });



});
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito confusa. Você tem um array de objetos e quer pegar um item através de um o atributo `id` deste objeto?

Comment: isso mesmo! mais tambem se é possivel passar diretamente o item para a nova pagina ao invez de passar o id e depois buscar o item ...

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi da seguinte forma :

1º Criei uma factory para facilitar o uso do  json:

```
app.factory('jsonExemplo', function($http) {
   return {
     getjson: function() {
        return $http.get('js/dados.php').then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
  }
}
});
```

2º Criei a listo do que eu queria no controller usando a Factory:

```
.controller('MeuController', function($scope,Exemplo ) {

jsonExemplo.getjson().then(function(data){
categorias:'1'

});

console.log($scope.dados);

});
```

3º Ja na Single pego o parametro e filtro pela ID:

```
app.controller('SingleController', function($scope,jsonExemplo, $stateParams,$filter, $timeout) {

    var myFilter = $filter;


jsonBaladas.getjson().then(function(data){

$scope.dados = myFilter('filter')(data.dados, {
        id:$stateParams.id

    })    
 console.log($scope.dados); 

});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes.

Para encontrar o objecto usando o ID pode simplesmente:

```
var idParaEncontrar = $stateParams.id;
var objectoEncontrado = undefined;
for(var i = 0; i < minhaColeccao.length: ++i){
    if(minhaColeccao[i].id === idParaEncontrar) {
        objectoEncontrado = minhaColeccao[id];
        break;
    }
}
if(objectoEncontrado !== undefined) {
    console.log("objecto encontrado")
}
```

Caso preferia usar uma biblioteca externa de uma olhadela no [`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org/), mais precisamente na função [`.find()`](http://underscorejs.org/#find).

Para passar o objecto para o `controller` pode optar por utilizar o `resolve` do [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Quando aceder a URL que tem o `resolve` definido, as funções são executadas e os resultados são injectados no `controller`.

O beneficio disto e que as funções podem devolver promessas e o Angular vai esperar que a promessa seja resolvida antes de instanciar o controlador e injectar o valor.

Assim, para o seu caso ficaria algo como:

```
resolve: {
    meuObjecto: (minhaColeccao, $stateParams) {
            // logica para encontrar o objecto, pode usar a mesma logica acima
        }]
},
```

Comment: não estou conseguindo usar o FOR dentro do meu controller... ele da erro de modulo ...  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module exemplo due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module inparty.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'exemplo.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: isso e um problema com o seu controller e não com o código em si. Veja se o modulo `exemplo.controllers` esta a ser criado correctamente.

Comment: esta sendo criado sim. :/